# Why does the answer turn out to be 0 instead of 0.009?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define KILOMETRE 9

main()
{
    float metre = KILOMETRE / 1000;
    printf("%f\n", metre);
}
```

The answer should be 0.009 as 9/1000=0.009

But after executing the program the output turns out to be 0.00.

Please help. :D

Comment: First of all what is KILO?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this expression

```
KILO/1000
```

the both operands are integers. So the result of the operation / for integer values is equal to 0.

You could write instead

```
KILO/1000.0f
```

In this case the compiler will deal with float numbers.

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: If you remember your integer math from elementary school, nine divided by a thousand is zero, remainder nine.

Comment: it it best to define KILOMETRE  as float instead of the divider

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are performing integer division. If both operands are of type `int`, the result will be `int` as well. In this case, when you divide two integers, the result will be truncated--that is, the fractional portion will be thrown out. You need to change the code to

```
KILO / 1000.
```

Notice the trailing decimal point. This tells the compiler that `1000` is a floating point, not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

When an arithmetic operation is performed on two integers (i.e., the two operands are integers), the result will be an integer. So in order to get a floating point output, rewrite the code as `float metre = (float) KILOMETRE / 1000;`